# optimizing data mining from google form for online statistics for recommendation system (Flask app delpoyed on Heroku)

Tags: flask, heroku, google-sheets, export-to-csv, recommendation-engine

I'm building the Flask app delpoyed on Heroku: recommendation system for the field of future study.

Now I'm stuck on the next question: for now, pupils can fill Google Form, their data adding to Google Sheets, and based on that I'm doing offline statistics. And now I want to implement live-statistics. Because of some "multiple response" questions, there is a problem to take new data from Google Sheets of form without converting data. If I will convert all responces each time, all of that will be not optimized. 
What is the best way to implement live-statistics: I don't want use Heroku database and I want to use my Google Sheet. Maybe there is some way to create and update csv file online after each new response?

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Google sheets have an API endpoint https://developers.google.com/sheets/api

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by Tin, you can use the Sheet API directly; [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) is a useful guide to get started for Python.

However, since you mention you want to use your Sheet directly, it would be a good idea to take a look at [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview), it can be quite useful for working with Google products directly and it's easy to use.

You can try with [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) on how to get started with Apps Script to work with Sheets. If you have any further questions, feel free to post them separately, the community will be more than happy to help.